# Difference between float-start and start-0

Tags: html, position, bootstrap-5, card

I am trying to replicate the following section layout in html Bootstrap5:
[image: Layout to replicate]

I am struggling with the positioning of the items. For the image, I use `float-start` which works as `float-end` moves it to the right.  However, `start-0` does not work. Are they not actually equivalent? Why one works and the other does not?

For the card, `start` and `top` classes do not work either. Why they do not work? How to move the card somewhere in the middle?

```
<section>
    <div class="position-relative">
        <div>
            <img src="img/zayed1200.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-3 float-start">
        </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="card bg-black shadow-lg rounded start-60 top-60">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title here</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Text of the card etc.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Apologies if I am missing something very basic, I'm self learning and may have some gaps in my basic knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the proper structure for the `.start-*` and `.top-*` classes to work.
If you check the docs here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/position/#arrange-elements you will see the following example showing the necessary parent `.position-relative` and the accompanied `.position-absolute` class on the element you are trying arrange:

```html
<div class="position-relative">
  <div class="position-absolute top-0 start-0"></div>
  <div class="position-absolute top-0 end-0"></div>
  <div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50"></div>
  <div class="position-absolute bottom-50 end-50"></div>
  <div class="position-absolute bottom-0 start-0"></div>
  <div class="position-absolute bottom-0 end-0"></div>
</div>
```

Also if you are not modifying BS and compiling from source, You will only have values of `0`, `50`, and `100` not `60`.